# Base32encode in Python3.8, compliant with RFC2938

Tags: python-3.x

I need a base32 encoding using the alphabet in [RFC2938](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2938#section-3.1.2). Alphabet being used is numbers 0-9 and letters A-V. Problem I am having is that Python3.8, which I have no choice in using here, only has base32encode & base32decode. It does not have base32hexencode & base32hexdecode, which were recently included in Python3.10. base32hexencode uses [The "Extended Hex" Base 32 Alphabet](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-7)

There is documentation in [RFC4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122) on implementing an encoding/decoding while avoiding name collisions (for UUIDs), but the implementation for the encoding and decoding are not the same and looks like a fair amount of time invested to understand and properly implement in python. How should this be approached? Do I just need to buck up and write a utility that implements the above?

Comment: You could probably just use base32encode and base32decode with a simple character mapping before or after to get what you need.

Comment: Ahh man...that is an easy and simple fix to my problem...you are awesome Mark Ransom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sympathize with your plight, I'm stuck with Python 3.8 as well.

Luckily the only difference between `b32encode` and `b32hexencode` is the alphabet used.  Python makes it trivially easy to convert from one alphabet to another using the `translate` function.

```
import uuid
u = uuid.uuid4()

base32_bytes = b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567='
base32hex_bytes = b'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV='
trans_to_hex = bytes.maketrans(base32_bytes, base32hex_bytes)

import base64
u32 = base64.b32encode(u.bytes).translate(trans_to_hex)
```